# Adding values to a new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an existing python array instantiated with zeros.  How do I iterate through and change the values?

I can't iterate through and change elements of a Python array?

```
num_list = [1,2,3,3,4,5,]
mu = np.mean(num_list)
sigma = np.std(num_list)
std_array = np.zeros(len(num_list))

for i in std_array:
        temp_num = ((i-mu)/sigma)
        std_array[i]=temp_num
```

This the error:
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Can you print this statement? I would like to see what it returns.  np.zeros(len(num_list))

Comment: @FranJ `[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]`

Answer (score 4):

In your code you are iterating over the elements of the `numpy.array` `std_array`, but then using these elements as indices to dereference `std_array`. An easy solution would be the following.

```
num_arr = np.array(num_list)
for i,element in enumerate(num_arr):
    temp_num = (element-mu)/sigma
    std_array[i]=temp_num
```

where I am assuming you wanted to use the value of the `num_list` in the first line of the loop when computing `temp_num`. Notice that I created a new `numpy.array` called `num_arr` though. This is because rather than looping, we can use alternative solution that takes advantage of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
std_array = (num_arr-mu)/sigma
```

This is equivalent to the loop, but faster to execute and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You `i` is an element from `std_array`, which is `float`. `Numpy` is therefore complaining that you are trying slicing with `float` where:

> only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`)
>   and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

If you don't have to use `for`, then `numpy` can broadcast the calculations for you:

```
(std_array - mu)/sigma
# array([-2.32379001, -2.32379001, -2.32379001, -2.32379001, -2.32379001,
   -2.32379001])
```